# mongodb aggregation: How can i add minutes to a date field and then compare it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to make a complex query.

I'm building a cinema application.
I want to make a validation check  for a new show. 
it will check if the show time is in a range of another show that plays in the same theater.
In order to know the end time of the range i need to add the number of minutes of the movie to the movie start time.

Important to note: The new show time is not yet stored in the DB. so it's in different timezone (let's say +2). so when we compare the dates we should take into effect the different timezones as well.
I changed the time of the new show to utc so i guess it solves the issue.

Here is the code i tried running. obviously is not working. I don't know can i add the movie Duration to the movie start:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
if (!req.body)
    return res.sendStatus(400);
let show = new Show(req.body);
startDateTime= moment.utc(show.dateTime);
console.log('startDateTime in utc');
console.log(startDateTime);
Show.aggregate([
    //next stage: add movies details
    {
        "$match": {
            "dateTime": { $gte: new Date(startDateTime)},
            "_TheaterId": show._TheaterId  
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: 'movies',
                localField: '_MovieId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'MovieDetails'
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$MovieDetails"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            { $add: [ "$dateTime", $MovieDetails.durationInMin * 60000 ] }: { $lte: new Date(startDateTime)} 
        }
    }

], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        //next(err);
        return res.json(err);
    } else {
        res.json(result);
    }
});
```

ANybody knows how can i add the minutes to the date field and then compare it to a different date?

Many thanks!

Here is a picture of the Db:

[image]

Comment: Try this `{ "$match": { "$expr": { $lte: [ { $add: [ "$dateTime", { $multiply: [ "$MovieDetails.durationInMin", 60000 ] } ] }, new Date(startDateTime) ] } }}`

Comment: can you please post your actual data instead of screenshots

Comment: ok i know what was the problem. your answer was perfect but i had to switch between 'lte' and 'gte' in my original query

Answer (score 0):

There is the [add function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) provided by moment.

so assuming your *startDateTime* is a  **moment object** :

> **startDateTime.add(20, 'minutes');**

Answer (score 0):

You can add minutes to the date by using the `moment()` as follows.

```js
// To add the five minutes  to the current date
var moment = require('moment'); // require
```

To get the current time using `moment()`:

Current time:

```js
datenow = moment()
```

To add the five minutes to the current date using `moment().add()`:

```js
datePulsFivemin = moment().add(5, 'm')//Add five minutes to the current work
```

To subtract the five minutes from the current date using `moment().subtract()`:

```js
dateSubractFivemin = moment().subtract(5, 'm') // Add a .format() if need of UTC format
```

To compare the date with other date using the `moment().isBefore()` and it will return Boolean:

```js
//Syntax
//sourcedate.isBefore(targetdate) 
moment().isBefore(datePulsFivemin)
```

Sample program:

```js
var moment = require('moment'); // require

// Current date
datenow = moment()


//Add five minutes to the current date
datePulsFivemin = moment().add(5, 'm')

//subtract five minutes from the current date
dateSubractFivemin = moment().subtract(5, 'm') //Add a .format() if need of UTC format

console.log(moment()) // Moment<2022-12-10T19:36:09+05:30>
console.log(datePulsFivemin.format()) // 2022-12-10T19:41:09+05:30
console.log(dateSubractFivemin.format()) // 2022-12-10T19:31:09+05:30
// TO compare the date
console.log(moment().isBefore(datePulsFivemin)) // true
console.log(moment().isBefore(dateSubractFivemin)) // false
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use moment.js as it [has been depreciated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). The developers have [released a list of libraries they recommend](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Increments a Date object by a specified number of time units.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/